# JOptionPane to get password

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, passwords, joptionpane

`JOptionPane` can be used to get string inputs from user, but in my case, I want to display a password field in `showInputDialog`.

The way I need is the input given by the user should be masked and the return value must be in `char[]`. I need a dialog box with a message, password field, and two buttons. Can that be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using [`JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29). Something like this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter a password:");
JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
panel.add(label);
panel.add(pass);
String[] options = new String[]{"OK", "Cancel"};
int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "The title",
                         JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                         null, options, options[1]);
if(option == 0) // pressing OK button
{
    char[] password = pass.getPassword();
    System.out.println("Your password is: " + new String(password));
}
```

Comment: JPasswordField(10) doesn't accept passwords longer that 10.  Better to make this much wider or use the no-arg constructor like @Adamski below. Also OK should be the default option because many users will out of habit hit Enter after typing their password.  If Cancel is default then typing password followed by enter will just cancel the dialog.

Comment: this one is good one ,a label with a JPasswordField in JOptionPane and in my case its accepting password longer than 10.

Comment: How do you give the password field the focus when the dialog appears?

Comment: This doesn't work. option == 1 when I press Enter in the password field.

Comment: pass options[0] to make OK the default. That will return option==0 when you press Enter in the password field.

Answer (score 48):

The easiest thing is to use `JOptionPane`'s [`showConfirmDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) method and to pass in a reference to a `JPasswordField`; e.g.

```
JPasswordField pf = new JPasswordField();
int okCxl = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, pf, "Enter Password", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

if (okCxl == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
  String password = new String(pf.getPassword());
  System.err.println("You entered: " + password);
}
```

**Edit**

Below is an example using a custom `JPanel` to display a message along with the `JPasswordField`.  Per the most recent comment, I've also (hastily) added code to allow the `JPasswordField` to gain focus when the dialog is first displayed.

```
public class PasswordPanel extends JPanel {
  private final JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(12);
  private boolean gainedFocusBefore;

  /**
   * "Hook" method that causes the JPasswordField to request focus the first time this method is called.
   */
  void gainedFocus() {
    if (!gainedFocusBefore) {
      gainedFocusBefore = true;
      passwordField.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
  }

  public PasswordPanel() {
    super(new FlowLayout());

    add(new JLabel("Password: "));
    add(passwordField);
  }

  public char[] getPassword() {
      return passwordField.getPassword();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      PasswordPanel pPnl = new PasswordPanel();
      JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane(pPnl, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

      JDialog dlg = op.createDialog("Who Goes There?");

      // Wire up FocusListener to ensure JPasswordField is able to request focus when the dialog is first shown.
      dlg.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
            pPnl.gainedFocus();
        }
      });

      if (op.getValue() != null && op.getValue().equals(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)) {
          String password = new String(pPnl.getPassword());
          System.err.println("You entered: " + password);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for.
BTW is there a way to **set message/body string** of that Dialog Box ?

Comment: The easiest way it to create a JPanel that contains both the JPasswordField along with a JLabel containing the desired text.

Comment: I know that already but I don't want to _open another frame during application is running_. So I wanted to use your solution with **message string**.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean re. opening another frame: the custom JPanel can be passed to the call to JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog as the message.  See my most recent edit.

Comment: Is good, but unfortunately the password field lacks focus, requiring an extra mouse-click to begin typing.

Comment: @AdamMackler: I've amended the code to account for this.

Comment: @Adamski Thanks.  When constructing the `JOptionPanel` I just overrode `selectInitialValue()` to `{ passwordField.requestFocusInWindow() }`

It's not clear why you're avoiding invoking `requestFocusInWindow()` more than once.  Also, I think you wrote `loginPnl` where you meant `pPnl`.

Comment: @AdamMackler: Thanks; corrected that typo.  Re. your comment I'm avoiding requesting focus more than once is to avoid situations like this: a) Display the password dialog, password field has focus. b) User enters password, tabs to "OK" and it about to dismiss but then has to switch to a different app. c) User switches back to Java app, dialog regains focus and password field re-requests focus (!) despite the user already having typed their password.

Comment: @Adamski That makes sense, but the one-line override of `selectInitialValue()` seems to do the same.  I'm not seeing the advantage of a 13-line solution that involves a new field, a new method, and adding a listener to the dialog.

Comment: Well like I said it was hastily put together.  Perhaps you should post your code as an alternative solution?

Comment: Great. That's awesome. I've used your class as a base for a slightly improved version that includes `String showDialog` methods. These contain the logic shown in the `main` method and `main` simply contains a call to `showDialog`.

Comment: I use listeners to set and restore the focus so I don't have to care about layout: `input.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {@Override public void focusLost(final FocusEvent event) {input.removeFocusListener(this);input.requestFocusInWindow();}}); input.addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener() {@Override public void hierarchyChanged(final HierarchyEvent event) {if ((event.getChangeFlags() & HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED) != 0) {input.removeHierarchyListener(this);input.requestFocusInWindow();}}});`

Answer (score 4):

You can create you're own dialog that extends JDialog and then you can put whatever you want in it.

Answer (score 3):

This dialogue looks a lot better if you do

```
dlg.setVisible(true);
```

Without that you can't see it at all.

Also

```
pPnl.gainedFocus();
```

should be

```
pPnl.gainedFocus();
```

Other than that it works great. Thanks for the code. Saved me time facing around with Swing.

Also, if you don't want to leave the dialogue running in the background every time you open it, you'll need to close it with something like

```
dlg.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(dlg, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
dlg.dispose(); // else java VM will wait for dialog to be disposed of (forever)
```

Answer (score 1):

A Kotlin solution based on [Adamski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8881370/2225787).

This time without buttons that takes focus, just enter password and press Enter, or Escape to discard input:

```
class PasswordPanel : JPanel(FlowLayout()) {

    private val passwordField = JPasswordField(20)
    private var entered = false

    val enteredPassword
        get() = if (entered) String(passwordField.password) else ""

    init {
        add(JLabel("Password: "))
        add(passwordField)
        passwordField.setActionCommand("OK")
        passwordField.addActionListener {
            if (it.actionCommand == "OK") {
                entered = true

                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/51356151/1020871
                SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(it.source as JComponent)
                    .dispose()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun request(passwordIdentifier: String) = apply {
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, this@PasswordPanel,
            "Enter $passwordIdentifier",
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
            null, emptyArray(), null)
    }

    companion object {

        fun requestPassword(passwordIdentifier: String) = PasswordPanel()
            .request(passwordIdentifier)
            .enteredPassword
    }
}
```

Usage: `PasswordPanel.requestPassword(passwordIdentifier)`

Answer (score 1):

An attempt to simplify the code after the original solution from [@Adamski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127479/adamski) and [@Peter West](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5263919/peter-west).

All the wiring is done in the PasswordPanel class and the client only calls the static getPassword method.

```
String passwordText = PasswordPanel.getPassword();
if (null != passwordText) {
    System.out.println("password: <" + passwordText + ">");
}
```

source:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class PasswordPanel extends JPanel {
    private final String password;

    private PasswordPanel(String prompt) {
        super(new FlowLayout());
        JPasswordField pwdField = new JPasswordField(12);
        add(pwdField);
        JOptionPane joptionPane = new JOptionPane(this, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        boolean responseOK = configure(joptionPane, prompt, pwdField).equals(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        this.password = responseOK ? String.valueOf(pwdField.getPassword()) : null;
    }

    public static String getPassword(){
        return new PasswordPanel("Input Password ... ").password;
    }

    private Object configure(JOptionPane jOptionPane, String prompt, JComponent pwdField) {
        JDialog jDialog = promptDialog(prompt, jOptionPane, pwdField);
        Object result = jOptionPane.getValue();
        jDialog.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(jDialog, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        jDialog.dispose();
        return result;
    }

    private JDialog promptDialog(String message, JOptionPane jOptionPane, JComponent pwdField) {
        JDialog dialog = jOptionPane.createDialog(message);
        dialog.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
                pwdField.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following class is an extension of [Adamski's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8881370/2225787):

```
package com.stackoverflow.swing;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;

/**
 * Class that creates a panel with a password field. Extension of Adamski's class
 *
 * @author adamski https://stackoverflow.com/users/127479/adamski
 * @author agi-hammerthief https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225787/agi-hammerthief
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8881370/2225787
 */
public class PasswordPanel extends JPanel {

  private final JPasswordField JFieldPass;
  private JLabel JLblPass;
  private boolean gainedFocusBefore;

  /**
   * "Hook" method that causes the JPasswordField to request focus when method is
   * first  called.
   */
  public void gainedFocus () {
    if (!gainedFocusBefore) {
      gainedFocusBefore = true;
      JFieldPass.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
  }

  public PasswordPanel (int length) {
    super(new FlowLayout());
    gainedFocusBefore = false;
    JFieldPass = new JPasswordField(length);
    Dimension d = new Dimension();
    d.setSize(30, 22);
    JFieldPass.setMinimumSize(d);
    JFieldPass.setColumns(10);
    JLblPass = new JLabel("Password: ");
    add(JLblPass);
    add(JFieldPass);
  }

  public PasswordPanel() {
    super(new FlowLayout());
    gainedFocusBefore = false;
    JFieldPass = new JPasswordField();
    Dimension d = new Dimension();
    d.setSize(30, 22);
    JFieldPass.setMinimumSize(d);
    JFieldPass.setColumns(10);
    JLblPass = new JLabel("Password: ");
    add(JLblPass);
    add(JFieldPass);
  }

  public char[] getPassword() {
    return JFieldPass.getPassword();
  }

  public String getPasswordString() {
    StringBuilder passBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    char[] pwd = this.getPassword();
    if (pwd.length > 0) {
      for (char c : pwd) {
        passBuilder.append(c);
      }
    }

    return passBuilder.toString();
  }

  private static String displayDialog (
    Component parent, final PasswordPanel panel, String title
  ) {
    String password = null;
    /* For some reason, using `JOptionPane(panel, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)`
    does not give the same results as setting values after creation, which is weird */
    JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane(panel);
    op.setMessageType(JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    op.setOptionType(JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    JDialog dlg = op.createDialog(parent, title);
    // Ensure the JPasswordField is able to request focus when the dialog is first shown.
    dlg.addWindowFocusListener (new WindowAdapter () {
      @Override
      public void windowGainedFocus (WindowEvent e) {
        panel.gainedFocus ();
      }
    });
    dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION); // necessary?

    dlg.setVisible (true);

    Object val = op.getValue ();
    if (null != val && val.equals (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)) {
      password = panel.getPasswordString();
    }

    return password;
  }

  public static String showDialog (Component parent, String title) {
    final PasswordPanel pPnl = new PasswordPanel();
    return displayDialog(parent, pPnl, title);
  }

  public static String showDialog (
    Component parent, String title, int passwordLength
  ) {
    final PasswordPanel pPnl = new PasswordPanel(passwordLength);

    return displayDialog (parent, pPnl, title);
  }

  public static String showDialog (String title) {
    return showDialog(null, title);
  }

  public static String showDialog (String title, int passwordLength) {
    return showDialog(null, title, passwordLength);
  }

  /**
   * Show a test dialog
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = PasswordPanel.showDialog ("Enter Your Password");
    System.out.println ("Entered Password: " + test);
    System.exit(0);
  }

}
```