# does not loop and display the error message

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch, joptionpane

Ok, I have this code that asks an input for a username and a password. I used `JOptionPane`. What I want with the program is to display an error message if the the input on the username field has a number, and goes back to the previous dialog box asking for the username again. I have this while loop yet it does not function the way it should. Please do help. The program does not show the error message on my `catch` method and neither does it loop for the dialog box to display.

```
public class SwingExercise {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  String name = "";
  String pw = "";
  boolean input = true;
  boolean hasDigit = false;

  while (input) {
    try {
      while (name.equals("")) {
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter username:");
        if (name.equals("")) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
              null, "No input.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          name = "";
        }
        while (hasDigit) {
          for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(name.charAt(i))) {
              throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
          }
          hasDigit = false;
        }
      }
      input = false;

      while (pw.equals("")) {
        pw = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter password:");
        if (pw.equals("")) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
              null, "No input.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          pw = "";
        }
      }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      System.exit(0);
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
          null, "Invalid input.", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
  }
}
```

Please do mention any comments regarding the other lines in my code and if there are any unnecessary lines. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I've formatted your code for style, so it's easier to read. (No changes other than whitespace.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that the value of hasDigit will always remain false. You probably will want to define hasDigit as true initially.

```
boolean hasDigit = true;
```

Comment: Oh yeah, so sorry. didn't see that one. I've been editing it too much. :)) Anyway, it now displays the error message, however, it proceeds to the password dialog box. I wanted it to go back to the name dialog box.

Comment: Well, set name= "" in the catch block and it'll do that.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. :) I'm just new with Java, that's why I ask these questions. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No problem. We were all new to Java once :)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be absolutley no way to get into the `while(hasDigit)` loop because you have it set to `false`, and there is nothing setting it to `true`.

Comment: I forgot what brought me back to this question, but I figured as long as I was here, I might as well leave the campground cleaner than I found it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on style, since you asked:

- In general, you want your `try()` blocks to be as short as possible, so it's clear which lines you're expecting to throw an exception. Otherwise you may unexpectedly catch an exception from a line that you didn't think could generate it, and then handle it incorrectly. This means the code will probably be longer, but it's far more important that it be easier to maintain and debug.
- When it's legitimate for a string to be `null`, it's common to write `if ("".equals(name))` rather than `if (name.equals(""))`. Since the hard-coded empty string can never be `null`, you needn't surround the code with a `try`/`catch` block.
- There's no need to set `name` or `pw` to the empty string inside an `if()` that tests to see if they're empty.
- You probably don't want to echo the password. See [JOptionPane to get password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881213/joptionpane-to-get-password).
- The code explicitly forbids digits in the `name` but accepts every other character, including punctuation and special characters. It's generally good programming practice to use a *whitelist* of acceptable input, rather than a *blacklist* of forbidden input. That way you'll never be surprised by invalid data that's unexpectedly accepted.
- The outermost `while()` loop will exit if the password is invalid, since `input` only depends on the `name`. Better to set `input` to `false` at the top of the loop, then set it to `true` if either input is invalid.
- Since the `name` and `pw` blocks are almost identical (they prompt for a non-empty string), consider extracting them into a helper function. You'll want to pass parameters that specify the prompt and whether or not to echo the input back to the user.