# Swing how to close JPanel programmatically

Tags: java, swing

My main class extends JPanel and I create a table  and a button on this panel.Now I want to close this panel when the user press it.On the internet closing examples are about JFrame.Is there solution for JPanel?

- There is a panel
- On Panel there is a table and a button
- I add an action listener to the button
- I want to close panel if user press button
- This is my code now I want when the user press the btnDelete then it close the panel

  public class ListUsers extends JPanel {

  ResultSet rs;
  ClientDAO dao;
  JScrollPane scrollPane;
  JTable table;
  Object columnId;

  public ListUsers() throws SQLException {

  ```
  dao = new ClientDAO();
  rs=dao.getUsers();
  ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();  
  int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();  

  Vector<String> columns = new Vector(columnCount);  

  //store column names  
  for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++)  
      columns.add(md.getColumnName(i));  

  Vector data = new Vector();  
  Vector row;  

  //store row data  
  while(rs.next())  
  {  
      row = new Vector(columnCount);  
      for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++)  
      {  
          row.add(rs.getString(i));  
      }  
      data.add(row);  
  }  





  table = new JTable(data, columns);  
  table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));  
  table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);  
  table.setVisible(true);  
  table.validate();
  table.setEnabled(true);
  add(table);




  table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {





             final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
             dialog.setSize(300, 200);
             dialog.setLayout(null);


             columnId = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),0);

             Integer no = new Integer(columnId.toString());
             final int i =no.intValue();

             String columnNo =columnId.toString();
             String name = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),1).toString();
             String surname = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),2).toString();
             String gender = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),3).toString();


             String labelText ="<html>Name :<b>"+name+"</b><br>Surname :<b>"+surname+"</b><br>Gender :<b>"+gender+"</b></html>";
             JLabel label=new JLabel(labelText);
             label.setVisible(true);
             label.setBounds(10,  10,300, 100);
             dialog.add(label);



             JButton btnUpdate= new JButton("Update");
             btnUpdate.setVisible(true);
             btnUpdate.setBounds(10,100,100,35);


             JButton    btnDelete= new JButton("Delete");
             btnDelete.setVisible(true);
             btnDelete.setBounds(150,100,100,35);




             dialog.add(btnDelete);
             dialog.add(btnUpdate);


             btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  dialog.setVisible(false);

              }
          });


             btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {




                  try {
                      dao.deleteUser(i);
                  } catch (SQLException e1) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                      e1.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  dialog.setVisible(false);


                  setVisible(false);
                  System.exit(0);



              }
          });

             dialog.setVisible(true);
  ```

Comment: You can hide it. `setVisible(false)`

Comment: I setVisible(false) however Panel still visible just the items on the panel are disappear.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide us with some of your code which produces the issue. Edit your question and add it there. Without more details it is hard to help further.

Comment: Also, do you want to dispose the panel? Are you going to open it again in the same state?

Comment: My ide don't recognize the dispose()

Comment: I don't think that's a good use of `JPanel`s. If you want something that closes you'll have to use some type of `Frame` or `Window`

Comment: Frame and Window may be good a solution however I write two hundred lines.Reconstructing may needs more time.

Answer (score 8):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  JComponent comp = (JComponent) e.getSource();
  Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp);
  win.dispose();
}
```

e.getSource(): Get Java `Component`

getWindowAncestor: Returns the first `Window`  ancestor of `Component`

win.dispose(): 
Releases all of the native screen resources used by this
     its subcomponents, and all of its owned children.

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: Here you go! Added!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to 'close' a JPanel, you can hide it.

```
myPanel.setVisible(false);
```

And if/when you want to 'open' it again:

```
myPanel.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: In this case, panel will continue running in the background.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to close your swing application when you press the button. You can just use:

`System.exit(0);`

Comment: @Harunergül Why did you select this answer as correct if it does not work for you.

Answer (score 3):

You may try using `Frame.pack()` again it worked for me.

Comment: or try one of following methods: 
setOpaque(false);
setEnabled(false);
setVisible(false);
removeAll();

Comment: Hope that helps someone, it was usefull for me that time

Answer (score 0):

When you extends a JPanel you import the necesary :

```
 JComponent comp = (JComponent) e.getSource();
  Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp);
  win.dispose();
```

but when you extend for a JFrame you just use this.dispose() or yourFrameInstance.dispose();