# Get String value from showOptionDialog

Tags: java

```
String[] enrollment = {"first Value", "second value"}

int enroll = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            "Please select your enrollment:", "Enrollment",
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
            enrollment, enrollment[1]);
```

How can I get the value from `enroll` (like first Value) and compare it in a if statement? Since enroll returns an integer variable.

I dont think this question is a duplicate as marked because I am just trying to get the value inside the integer, store it and compare later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JOptionPane to get password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881213/joptionpane-to-get-password)

Comment: @CoderNeji Not sure how that is a duplicate.

Comment: Why pass in the `enrollment` array twice?

Comment: `enrollment[1]` is the default option to be selected.

Comment: its the same way you'll get the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to do something like this in your if/else checking

```
  if (enroll != JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
      System.out.println(enrollment [enroll ]);
    } else {
      System.out.println("No option selected".);
    }
```

Comment: so this is what I am trying to achieve
 `if ( first value && somethingElseHere < integer ){`
      `do something}`

how can I store the value inside enroll to compare it with an integer?

Comment: So basically enroll stores option from enrolment which can either be `first Value` or `second value`. But since enroll is an integer value, I cannot compare the actual value (that being `first value` or `second value`). Is there a way I can get the actual values from enroll on selecting it from the dialog box. ? I hope that was a bit more clear?

Comment: returned 'enroll' will be the index for the selected option from the two. If enroll is 0 first value is selected if enroll is 1 second value is selected. Thats it.

Comment: so this resolves your issue or there is something else?

Comment: Great...Kindly accept this is an answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (enroll == 0) {    // 0 here is the first thing in the enrolment array
     // do something

}
```

Comment: `if (enroll == 0) { }` don't use `=` for comparison