# Masking password in executable created from java

Tags: java

I've written a small java program that required user input for login, to do other stuff. Executing the .jar file of my program masks the password as expected.

However, when I create a .exe from the same .jar and run it, the application doesn't mask the password. What should I do to make the .exe mask the password?

```
Console cons = System.console();
        if (cons == null) {
            System.err.println("No console.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        String username = cons.readLine("Enter username: ");
        char[] passwd = cons.readPassword("Enter Password: ");
        String password = new String(passwd);
```

I'm using Console.readPassword to mask the password and I used lanuch4j to create my .exe

Comment: Do the generally right thing: use some secure hash function to hash the password, only store the hash, and when someone enters their password, check that the hash matches the hash of the correct password.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think he's talking about echoing the password on the terminal.

Comment: How did you create an exe from the jar file?

Comment: I used launch4j to create the .exe

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is a command line only application, it may be possible for you to show a dialog popup just for user credentials, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881213/joptionpane-to-get-password). The only case this would not work is if GUI is not available (remote text-only session or some server without GUI installed).